# Custom Composite formatTextItemValue

Tags: webforms

I created a Custom Composite, but I have some display difficulties.

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\dvc_composite\Element;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\webform\Element\WebformCompositeBase;

/**
 * Provides a 'dvc_composite'.
 *
 * Webform composites contain a group of sub-elements.
 *
 *
 * IMPORTANT:
 * Webform composite can not contain multiple value elements (i.e. checkboxes)
 * or composites (i.e. webform_address)
 *
 * @FormElement("dvc_composite")
 *
 * @see \Drupal\webform\Element\WebformCompositeBase
 * @see \Drupal\dvc_composite\Element\WebformExampleComposite
 * @see \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformElementBase
 */
class WebformExampleComposite extends WebformCompositeBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getInfo() {
    return parent::getInfo() + ['#theme' => 'dvc_composite'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getCompositeElements(array $element) {
    $elements = [];
    $elements['piece'] = [
      '#type' => 'managed_file',
      '#title' => 'Fichier',
      '#max_filesize' => '5',
      '#file_extensions' => 'pdf',
      '#file_help' => 'help',
      '#wrapper_type'=> 'container',
    ];

    $elements['radio_etat_piece'] = [
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('Etat Pièce'),
      '#options' => 'etat_piece',
      '#wrapper_type'=> 'container',
    ];

    $elements['motif_rejet_piece'] = [
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Motif'),
      '#options' => 'motifs_pieces_non_conformes',
    ];

    return $elements;
  }
...
}
```

I would like to display **formatTextItemValue** items from my Custom Composite like this :

```
link_to_my_file.pdf

Etat Piece : Display Value

Motif: Display Value
```

I coded this, but I can't get the link to my file :

```
  protected function formatTextItemValue(array $element, WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, array $options = []) {
    $value = $this->getValue($element, $webform_submission, $options);
    $lines = [];
    if (!empty($value['piece'])) {
        $lines['piece'] = $value['piece'];
    }
    if (!empty($value['radio_etat_piece'])) {
        $lines['radio_etat_piece'] = $value['radio_etat_piece'];
    }
    if (!empty($value['motif_rejet_piece'])) {
        $lines['motif_rejet_piece'] = $value['motif_rejet_piece'];
    }
    return $lines;
  }
```

can someone help me, please ?

Comment: Where are you trying to get the link?

Comment: Hello, in the result tab of all webform submissions.